# Javascript/JQuery: Assign a whole line of code to a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

Is it possible to assign a whole line of code to a function parameter? Take this example:

```
function testFunc(parameter1){
    parameter1;
}

testFunc($(".someClass").text("someText"));
```

When the function is used with that parameter, can the `parameter1` be replaced by the line of code?

I'm new with JavaScript and jQuery, so I'm just curious if this is possible. I did not see any questions like this asked before. But if it was asked, a link to the question would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That is not a line of code passed... it is an expression that results in a jQuery object, which is passed to the function. If you want to pass a callback it needs to be an actual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are inventing the callback :)

Pass an actual function and call it with ();

```
function testFunc(callback){
    callback();
}

testFunc(function(){$(".someClass").text("someText");});
```

Comment: How about having no parameters and instead using `arguments[0]`? Would that work?

Comment: How can it be done? Would it be like `arguments[0]();` instead of `callback()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done , as jQuery will eveluate it and return a object.

Answer (score 0):

The key insight here is that a function can be treated like any other variable.

For example:

```
var i = 1;
var f = function() { console.log('hello!'); };
```

Here `f` is a value, just like `i` is, but you can *invoke* it just like any other function:

```
f(); // prints 'hello!' in the console
```

Because it is a value, you can pass it to another function:

```
function g(h) { h(); }

g(f); // prints 'hello!' in the console
```

Take the time to ensure you understand the above code. I've deliberately used vague names so you can learn the mechanics. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How about having no parameters and instead using `arguments[0]`? Would that work?

Comment: Sure, but there's no point in not specifying a name to bind the argument to. The only reason to do that may be if you allow a variable number of arguments, where the index of each does not have a distinct purpose to the others.

Comment: How can it be done? Would it be like `arguments[0]();` instead of `callback();`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean `arguments[0]();` instead of `f();` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments aren't assigned to functions, they are passed/sent/[insert other synonym here].

Anything that is an expression (any code which evaluates to some value) can be passed around.

In your exemple `$(".someClass").text("someText")` is an expression which evaluates to a jQuery object, so you can use this unit of code as a function's argument without any doubt.

However, if you want to pass around some code which has to be executed as part of an existing function's process, you must use a function expression which encapsulates that behavior.

E.g.

```
function executor(task) {
    task();
}


executor(function () {
    //code to be executed by the executor
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass function callback like regular primitive variable

In your case you should check param type before execution

```
function testFunc(parameter1){

    if(typeof parameter1==="undefined"){
       //arguments[0] will fall here
       console.log("No arguments case. parameter1 not defined")
    }
    else //function check 
    if(typeof parameter1==="function"){
       //you can parameter function here.
        return parameter1();
    }
    else{
        //regular case value or object, other than function types fall here
        console.log("not a function, received param type: "+ typeof(parameter1));
        return parameter1;
    }

}

$(function (){
    //let us say you have below vars
    var primitiveVar="test",
        fun = function(){console.log("function fun call")};

    //no args here
    testFunc();

    //sending primitiveVar
    testFunc(primitiveVar);

    //below is your call with jQuery Obj
    testFunc($(".someClass").text("someText"));
});
```